# Prove that $\{x_n\}$ is bounded if $f(x_n)$ is bounded $\forall f\in X'$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Given a normed space $X$ and $x_n \in X$, for any $ f\in X'$ (dual space of $X$), $f(x_n)$ is bounded. Try to prove that $\{x_n\}$ is bounded.

My thought is: if $\{x_n\}$ is not bounded, then for any $M>0$, we find a $||x_n||>M$. And then there exist a $f\in X'$ s.t. $|f(x_n)|=||x_n||>M$, but that doesn't mean that $f(x_n)$ is not bounded.

Comment: As a corollary of the Hahn-Banach theorem, one has: $$\forall n\in\mathbb{N},\|x_n\|_X=\sup_{f\in X',\|f\|_{X'}\leqslant 1}|f(x_n)|.$$ That might be overkill but this is the only thing that came to my mind.

Comment: @C.Falcon Thanks for your attention! I came up with this corollary, but still cannot find a proof. I cannot see an advantage of using this corollary over directly using Hahn-Banach theorem.

Comment: You can maybe use directly Hanh-Banach theorem, however the corollary I stated has a nice form and is often use in functional analysis. If you want I can post a proof of this corollary.

Comment: @C.Falcon Thanks! I know the proof of this corollary already.

Comment: You have to combine the *norm formula* in C. Falcon's comment with the uniform boundedness principle in $(X',\|\cdot\|_{X'})$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each $x\in X$ defines an element of $X''$ sending $f\in X'$ to $f(x)$. Let $\phi:X\to X''$ be the map that sends $x\in X$ to this corresponding element of $X''$, so for $x\in X$ and $f\in X'$, $\phi(x)(f)=f(x)$.  For $x\in X$ and $f\in X'$, $|\phi(x)(f)|=|f(x)|\leq \|f\|\|x\|$, which shows that $\|\phi(x)\|\leq \|x\|$.  As in [a comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1591650/prove-that-x-n-is-bounded-if-fx-n-is-bounded-forall-f-in-x#comment3240862_1591650) by [C. Falcon](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/285416/c-falcon), it is a consequence of the Hahn Banach theorem that $\|\phi(x)\|=\|x\|$ for each $x\in X$.

As in [a comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1591650/prove-that-x-n-is-bounded-if-fx-n-is-bounded-forall-f-in-x#comment3243026_1591650) by [Jochen](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/38982/jochen), the Uniform Boundedness Principal can be applied to $\{\phi(x_n)\}\subset X''$, as you have $\{\phi(x_n)(f)\}$ bounded for each $f\in X'$, hence $\{\phi(x_n)\}$ is bounded.  Because of the fact mentioned in the previous paragraph that $\|\phi(x_n)\|=\|x_n\|$ for each $n$, this means $\{x_n\}$ is also bounded.

Comment: Good day. I thought, you might give a hint on this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1745355/approximate-spectral-decomposition. Me, and the answerer, struggle with the methods of computing the subspace dimension from the contour integral construction of projection.