# Limit of sesquilinear forms is a sesquilinear form

Tags: functional-analysis, limits, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory, sesquilinear-forms

Suppose $P_n$ is a monotone sequences of orthogonal projections in a complex Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. I want to show that the limit of the sesquilinear forms defined by:

$\Gamma_n(x,y)=(x,P_n y)$ where $x,y$ are in $\mathcal{H}$.

That is the limit defined by $\Gamma(x,y)= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \Gamma_n(x,y)$ exists.

I think I ought to use the fact that the Hilbert space is complete in some sense and that the inner product is continuous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:** There is nothing about completeness of $\mathcal{H}$ needed to carry out of the following steps.

Because $P_n$ is monotone, then $(P_nx,x)$ is monotone in $n$ for each fixed $x$, and is bounded above by $(x,x)$, which forces convergence of $\lim_n(P_n x,x)$ for all $x$. Then, using polarization, the following expression must also have a limit in $n$ for every fixed $x,y \in \mathcal{H}$:
$$
        (P_nx,y) = \frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=0}^{3}i^{n}(P_n(x+i^ny),x+i^n y)
$$
Therefore the following limit exists for all $x,y\in\mathcal{H}$:
$$
         \Gamma(x,y) = \lim_n (P_nx,y).
$$
Because the limit exists for all $x,y$, you can show that $\Gamma$ is a sesquilinear form. And it's easy to check that $0 \le \Gamma(x,x)=\overline{\Gamma(x,x)} \le (x,x)$ for all $x$ because this is inherited from $(P_nx,x)$.

If you want to represent $\Gamma(x,y)=(Px,y)$ for some bounded linear operator $P$, then you'll need completeness.

Comment: Hello. Would you mind to take a look at my question? It's also related to spectral decomposition and strangely enough nobody on SE could comment on it. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1745355/approximate-spectral-decomposition