# If I and J are isomorphic ideals of a ring R, does it follow that $R/I \simeq R/J$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

The title pretty much sums it up. We know that $R/I \simeq R/J$ does not necessarily imply $ I \simeq J$. But does the converse hold? I can't find any counterexample and all my efforts in proving it seem to me rather sketchy.

Comment: $R=\mathbb{Z}$, $I=2\mathbb{Z}$ and $J=3\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Isomorphic as what? Modules?

Comment: The counterexample above nails the question, although my real doubt was whether given two different direct sums of a semisimple ring $R = L \oplus J$ and $R=L' \oplus I$ with $I \simeq_R J$ as R-modules, would it follow $L \simeq l'$

Comment: @proofromthebook, in that case you do get the conclusion you want. This follows from example from the Krull-Schmidt theorem.

Comment: @MarianoSuaréz-Alvarez that's interesting but still that would only work provided the direct summands were indecomposable. I don't think we have enough information to assert that.

Comment: Why would we need the direct summands to be indecomposable?

Comment: That's the Krull-Schmidt version I know. I don't remember quite the details fo the proof,but can we drop the indecomposable assumption?

Answer (score 3):

All non-zero ideals of $R=\mathbb Z$ are isomorphic. Are the corresponding quotients isomorphic?

Comment: Hello, Mariano. Would you mind to give a hint on the spectral decomposition? Me, and the answerer struggle with computing the subspace dimension from the contour integral construction of a projector. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1745355/approximate-spectral-decomposition

Answer (score 0):

No. Take a field $F$ and consider the ring $R=F[X]$. The ideals $I=(X-1)$ and $J=(X^2-1)$ are both isomorphic to $R$, but
$$R/I\sim F, \quad R/J\simeq F[X]/(X-1)\times F[X]/(X+1)\simeq F\times F,$$
which can't be isomorphic, since the latter has zero-divisors, while the former has not.

Comment: (One could factor out the idea common to your answer and mine: all non-zero ideals in a principal ideal domain are isomorphic and the corresponding quotients seldom are)