# Function $f$ such that $f''\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, unbounded-operators

Let us assume that $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and $f''\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ ($f'$ - first derivative,$f''$ - second derivative), i.e. $f$ is square-integrable, $f$ is differentiable, its first deriviative is absolutely continuous and second derivative of $f$ (which is defined almost everywhere) is square-integrable.

What might be said about the limits:

$$ \lim_{x\to\pm\infty} f(x)$$

and

$$ \lim_{x\to\pm\infty} f'(x).$$

Is it true that $f'\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$?

Note that if $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and $f'\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ then $(|f|^2)'=\overline{f'}f+\overline{f}f'\in L(\mathbb{R})$ by Schwarz inequality and $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty} f(x) = 0$.

Comment: Note that if $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and $f'\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ then $(|f|^2)'=\overline{f'}f+\overline{f}f'\in L(\mathbb{R})$ by Schwarz inequality and $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty} f(x) = 0$.(how are you concluding that can you please elaborate)

Answer (score 1):

Hints: If $f,f''\in L^2(\Bbb R)$ does it follow that $f'\in L^2$? Look at the Fourier transform.

About limits at infinity: If $f$ is absolutely continuous, $f'\in L^2$ and $a<b$ then $$|f(b)-f(a)|=\left|\int_a^bf'(t)\,dt\right|\le(b-a)^{1/2}||f'||_2,$$so $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $f,f'$ are absolutely continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ with $f,f''\in L^2$. Then $ff''\in L^1$, which means that the following limits exist
$$
          \int_{0}^{\pm\infty}ff''dt=-f(0)f'(0)+\lim_{x\rightarrow\pm\infty}f(x)f'(x).
$$
If either of these limits is non-zero, then the following diverges in magnitude to $\infty$:
$$
          \int_{0}^{\infty}ff'dt= \left.\frac{f^2}{2}\right|_{0}^{\infty}.
$$
But that is impossible because $f\in L^2$. Therefore $\lim_{x\rightarrow\pm\infty}f(x)f'(x)=0$. Knowing that gives $f'\in L^2$ because the right side of the following must converge:
$$
      \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f'|^2dt=f\overline{f}'|_{-\infty}^{\infty}+\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f\overline{f}''dt
$$

Comment: Hello. If you remember, we recently had a chat regarding http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1745355/approximate-spectral-decomposition. I don't know if it might be interesting for you, but I could go a bit further on this matter.

Comment: you are just working with $lim_{x\to \infty } f(x)f'(x)$ exists and non-zero case while deriving a contradiction . Also there are other possibilities, the limit may not exists.

Comment: @BiplabDas : The limits exist because the integrals on the left converge absolutely, and the limits on the right are equal to values of improper integrals on the left. The assumption that $f,f^{''}\in L^2$ forces that.

Comment: Also how is that happening..
$$
          \int_{0}^{\pm\infty}ff''dt=-f(0)f'(0)+\lim_{x\rightarrow\pm\infty}f(x)f'(x).
$$??

Comment: @Billa : The last two equalities follow from integration by parts, knowing that $f,f^{''}\in L^2$ gives $ff^{''}\in L^1$, which forces the two limits on the right to exist because the integrals on the left are absolutely convergent.